# How to make a ListFragment with multiple lists (Top and Bottom)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, slidingmenu

I am using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for my App and for the Menu, I got a simple ListFragment working. But that is just 1 straight list of 5 options. What I want is to have 3 settings at the top and 2 at the bottom (Hence, I thought multiple lists).

What I want is something similar to this Foursquare menu:

[image]

Can I do this with a ListFragment?

Currently, my ListFragment looks like this -

```
public class MenuListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity());

        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Home", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Help", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Settings", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));

        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Feedback", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Rate this App", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }



    private class SampleItem {
        public String tag;
        public int iconRes;
        public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
            this.tag = tag; 
            this.iconRes = iconRes;
        }
    }

    public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

        public MenuAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_row, null);
            }
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

And the menu_list XML is very simple -

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

But now I am trying to convert this into 2 lists, one at the top and one at the bottom. I changed the layout to the following but I don't think I am doing it the right way -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions? How exactly would the ListFragment change to handle 2 lists? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think add this two item as list footer...

Comment: Ok, I will try that out